# Scaling down a high resolution set of co-ordinates?

Tags: c#, scaling, dynamic, dimensions

Here is some background to the problem. We are working with an EyeVis wall setup, see this link: http://www.eyevis.co.uk/

The EyeVis wall can have any number of 'windows' displayed on the wall at any time. We query the wall for its size dimensions, and then query it for a list of all the windows currently being displayed on the wall. This comes back as a set of co-ordinates as follows:

> Left, Top, Width, Height

So at this stage we have the size of the wall, and the co-ordinates of each window being displayed within that wall. 
What we need to do is display a representation of the wall's layout on a monitor being viewed by the controller. The controller will then select one of the windows (from the monitor) and this window will be enlarged on the EyeVis wall.

I have tried a few things, in the hope that there might be a simple way to achieve this. One idea I had was this:

1. Create a panel in code with the dimensions of the wall.
2. Add each window to this panel using the co-ordinates.
3. Add the main panel to a form and dock the panel

I thought this would auto scale all the panels within the main panel and we would see the layout, but docking at runtime doesn't seem to behave the way I imagined?

This is the code I had: (Using C#)

```
Panel mainPanel = new Panel();

mainPanel.Width = eyeVisWallWidth;
mainPanel.Height = eyeVisWallHeight;

foreach (Window thisWindow in windowList)
{
    Panel newWindow = new Panel();

    newWindow.Top = thisWindow.windowTop;
    newWindow.Width = thisWindow.windowWidth;
    newWindow.Height = thisWindow.windowHeight;
    newWindow.Left = thisWindow.windowLeft;

    Label newLabel = new Label();
    newLabel.Text = thisWindow.windowID.ToString() + ":" + newWindow.Height + ":" + newWindow.Width;
    newWindow.Controls.Add(newLabel);
    newWindow.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;

    mainPanel.Controls.Add(newWindow);
}

this.panel1.Controls.Add(mainPanel);

mainPanel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
mainPanel.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;
```

So now I'm starting to think this might have to be solved with math, which is really not my strong point. Does anyone have any advice or a pointer to something which might help me with this?

Any help appreciated!
Regards
Adrian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forgot to close thise, we just ended up dividing all the co-ordinates by a common factor.

Comment: +1; Definitely the right answer, so no need to close the question.  "Scaling" = multiplying.  You're scaling to a smaller size, so you multiply to a value less than 1 (e.g. 0.6).  You scale everything evenly, so multiply everything by the same value.  Dividing by a value greater than 1 is mathematically equivalent (multiplying by 0.6 is equal to dividing by 5/3rds).